# How do I prevent auto mount for one of my external hdds in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, external-hdd, automount

For one of my external hard drives, I want to prevent Ubuntu 22.04 to automount it.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

On Kubuntu go into Settings > System Settings > Hardware > Removable Storage and then under Removable Devices 'unclick' > Mount all removable media at login  and also 'unclick' > Automatically mount all removable media when attached. Then there are settings for > Device overrides, that allows you to individually set which devices you want to automount.

I know this is Kubuntu and you asked for Ubuntu but I'm sure they have similar automount settings, they're probably organized a little differently.